# Change minimum quantity in shopping cart for bundled products

Tags: magento-1.7, bundled-product, bundle-product, quantity, shopping-cart

I have a bundled product and the Ship Bundle Items option is on Together.

Every single product is put on a minimum quantity of 1.

But if I add the bundled product to the shopping cart it adds 8 items (witch is the default setting in the system -> configuration part) instead of 1

Comment: how many bundle product are associated with your main product ?

Comment: It is one bundle product with 40 choices of simple products. And a view products that you can choose as extra option.